# Pull back of sheaves has left adjoint if and only if the morphism between topological spaces is a local homeomorphism

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory, locales

I am looking for a way to show that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a local homeomorphism of topological spaces if and only if $f^* :\operatorname{Sh}(Y)\rightarrow \operatorname{Sh}(X)$ has a left adjoint.
Also can you please give an example?

Comment: Off the top of my head, some ways to get started would include: first, take some local homeomorphism, such as the canonical covering map $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$, and see what the left adjoint would be in that case.  And conversely, take some example of a map which is not a local homeomorphism, such as a projection map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, and see why pullback along that map does not have a left adjoint (looking for some colimit which is not preserved would probably be the most promising route there).

Comment: I don't think this is true. Étale geometric morphisms are different from essential geometric morphisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample.

Consider the Sierpiński space $S$: it has two points, say $0$ and $1$, and the open sets are precisely $\emptyset$, $\{ 1 \}$, and $S$.
A sheaf $F$ on $S$ is completely determined by the data of $F (S)$, $F (\{ 1 \})$, and the restriction $F (S) \to F (\{ 1 \})$.
Conversely, any data of that form determines a sheaf on $S$.
Thus $\textbf{Sh} (S)$ is equivalent to the arrow category $[\mathbf{2}, \textbf{Set}]$.

Now, consider the inclusion $i : \{ 0 \} \hookrightarrow S$.
The pullback functor $i^* : \textbf{Sh} (S) \to \textbf{Set}$ sends a sheaf $F$ on $S$ to the stalk $F_0$, which is naturally isomorphic to $F (S)$ (since the only open neighbourhood of $0$ is $S$).
Under the identification of $\textbf{Sh} (S)$ with $[\mathbf{2}, \textbf{Set}]$, this corresponds to the functor $\operatorname{dom} : [\mathbf{2}, \textbf{Set}] \to \textbf{Set}$ that sends a map to its domain.
This functor has a left adjoint, namely the functor that sends a set $X$ to the map $\textrm{id}_X$.
But $\{ 0 \} \hookrightarrow S$ is not a local homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you, what if instead of local homeomorphisem we have an etale map? What is the difference?

Comment: Étale geometric morphisms correspond exactly to local homeomorphisms, but there is nothing particularly deep about this.