# Left adjoint to inverse image sheaf

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, adjoint-functors

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a local homeomorphism. How should I show that the inverse image functor $f^*: Sh(Y) \rightarrow Sh(X)$ has a left adjoint?

I think it is because when we have a local homeomorphism, a sheaf $F$ on $X$ and $G$ on $Y$ then $f^{-1}(G)$ will be a sheaf itself and it does not need shifification.... but to be honest I have no idea to prove this....

Comment: It is easiest to work with the definition of sheaf in terms of espaces étalés here.

Comment: Would you please explain more?

Comment: Recall that an étalé space over $X$ is just a local homeomorphism $p:F\to X$ and that there is an equivalence of categories between the category of étalé space over $X$ and the category of sheaves. Under this equivalence, the pullback functor maps an étalé space $G\to Y$ to its pullback $G\times_Y X\to X$. Can you find the left adjoint from here ?

Comment: However, you said that the construction of $f^{-1}G$ does not require sheafification if $f$ is a local homeomorphism. This is not true take $f:\{0,1\}\to \{0\}$ and any sheaf $G$ on $\{0\}$, then you will need to sheafify $f^{-1}(G)$ in order to get the correct $\Gamma(\{0,1\},f^{-1}(G) )$.

Comment: I think I got it now! Thanks.  If $f$ is not a local homeomorphism then $f^*$ will not have a left adjoint?

Comment: No, $f^{-1}$ may have a left adjoint even if $f$ is not a local homeomorphism. Zhen Lin gave very recently a nice counter-example here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4096192/pull-back-of-sheaves-has-left-adjoint-if-and-only-if-the-morphism-between-topolo but the question is closed (I don't know why) and I don't know if you can see it. Anyway, if you find the left adjoint, you should write an answer to your own question.

Comment: Oh yes got it. Iam looking for an example of on inverse image sheaf without left adjoint...

Comment: How can I delet it from answers? I wrongly posted my comment as an answer

Comment: @user850424 you click on the "delete" button under your answer.

Comment: There is no delete botton there....

Comment: Just edit, share and more